# SSL Problem with GAE App Engine w/o custom domain/SSL certificate

Tags: django, ssl, google-app-engine-python

I deployed my locally functioning django project with two apps to the GAE.
I also tested the MySQL DB at GCP by using the proxy tool provided by GCP.
Although I have successfully deployed the project to the App Engine, it is not working on the GAE.
I tested the URL with Chrome, IE and Safari.

This is what Chrome says:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection <project-id>.oa.r.appspot.com sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

This is what curl says:

```
(ll_env)> curl https://<project-id>.oa.r.appspot.com
curl : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At line:1 char:1
+ curl https://<project-id>.oa.r.appspot.com
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I tested following settings without success:

- USE_X_FORWARDED_HOST = True on the settings.py
- ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'] on the settings.py

I installed Wireshark and captured the connection setup. App Engine seems to reset my connection request.

Comment: I switched to a different ISP and it worked, both http and https.
This has something to do with the ISP settings but I do not know how/why. I know that this particular ISP is using something called "Internet Guard" to deny traffic to malicious sites.

Comment: I switched back to the problematic ISP and changed my DNS to Google DNS and it works again!